# WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming requires an optional argument

Tags: javascript, parameters, webassembly

I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: second argument must be an object` error when I run the following code:

```js
async function loadWasm(url) {
  const fetchPromise = fetch(url)
  const { module, instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetchPromise)
  // [...]
}
loadWasm('http://localhost:3000/path/to/file.wasm')
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiateStreaming), it says that the second argument of `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming` (`importObject`) is optional, so I don't understand why the browser makes it mandatory nonetheless?

*I've tested this in Firefox 78.7.0esr (64-bit) and Chrome 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit). In case it's of any importance, the code is transpiled with webpack 5 in a ruby on rails 6.1 application.*

Update:

I opened [an issue on mdn's github repository](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/2008) thinking the documentation might need an update. So far it seems the [documentation is good](https://webassembly.org/docs/web/#webassemblyinstantiatestreaming) so it might be an implementation issue. To be confirmed.

Update:

It's neither an implementation issue nor a documentation mistake. I posted my conclusion about this issue in the answer below.

Comment: Noting that there’s now a spec issue at https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/issues/1284

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/issues/1284#issuecomment-772286062

> It is required only if the module you're instantiating actually imports something.

It's marked as optional in the documentation because it's not always needed, not because we have the choice to provide it or not. It's the wasm package that dictates whether it is optional or required.